# Expected value of a function vs average value

Tags: probability, integration, average, means

I don't understand the different between these two. For example, the average value of $\sin ^{2}\theta$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$ on $x∈[0,2\pi]$ according to the mean formula $${\bar  {f}}={\frac  {1}{b-a}}\int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx.$$

However, WolframAlpha suggests that the expected value, $\operatorname {E} (\sin^2{x})=0.432...$

I don't understand what the different between these two is.

Comment: what WolframAlpfa expression did you evaluate?

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov average of sinx^2

Comment: I mean, write the exact formula in the Mathematica language

Comment: What is meant by $\mathbb{E}(\sin^2 x)$? Is $\sin^2 x$ a random variable?

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov I've never used Mathematics. I don't know its language.

Comment: What did you type in WA's window?

Comment: @Did I typed in `average of sinx^2`

Comment: And WA explains what they do in the "Input interpretation" frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it.

You seem to evaluate [this expresion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expectation%20Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2): `Expectation Sin[x]^2` but it's related to normal distribution of $x$. And the formula from your question is related to uniformly distributed $x$.